# Wildfy add ManagedExecutorService

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

I want to add new `ManagedExecutorService` resource to **WildFly 10**.

I edit **standalone.xml**, and add line to `<managed-executor-services>`:

```
<managed-executor-service 
    name="test" 
    jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/test" 
    context-service="test" 
    long-running-tasks="true"
/>
```

After restarting **wildfy** I can't find - *java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/test* - in my JNDI view, and of course can't find this resource by `InitialContext`.

What I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing  a lot of experiments I delete property `context-service` in `<managed-executor-service>` and it works!

After it I can see *java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/test* in JNDI view.

Now my `<managed-executor-services>` see like that:

```
<managed-executor-service 
    name="test" 
    jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/test" 
    long-running-tasks="true"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, because you probably had not also configured a context service named "test"